# Spectrum of operator : $Tf(x)=\dfrac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Problem :

---

Let :

$$T~:~L^{2}(\mathbb{R})\to L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$$
Such that :

$$Tf(x)=\dfrac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$$

---

I'm going to find the spectrum of the above operator $T$

the operator $T$ are self -adjoins and $||T||$=1
We know that :

$$\sigma (\lambda)=\{\lambda\in\mathbb {C}~,~(T-\lambda f)\text{not invertible}\}$$
I'm start by :

$$Tf=\lambda f$$

So :

$$f(x)+f(-x)=2\lambda f(x)$$

So :

$$f(-x)=(2\lambda -1)f(x)$$

Also

$$f(x)=(2\lambda -1)f(-x)$$

This mean :

$$(2\lambda -1)^{2}f(x)=f(x)$$

So :
$$2\lambda -1=±1 \implies \lambda =0,1$$

Finally:
$$\sigma(\lambda)=\{0,1\}$$

Any other ideas?

Comment: The operator is a projection onto even functions. The spectrum of every nontrivial projection consists of $0$ and $1.$

Comment: Hint...Very nice 

Comment: Yes, and $\lambda = 0$ corresponds to odd functions, while $\lambda = 1$ is associated to even functions.

Comment: Starting with $Tf=\lambda f$ will get the point spectrum. To characterize all of $\sigma$ you also need to find continuous and essential spectrum.